# Printing dictionaries in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, printing

I want to convert:

Initial scores:
{1: 0.25, 2: 0.25, 3: 0.25, 4: 0.25}

Into:

Initial scores:
0.2500 2: 0.2500 3: 0.2500 4: 0.2500

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {1: 0.25, 2: 0.25, 3: 0.25, 4: 0.25}

result = " ".join([str(k) + ": " + "{0:.4f}".format(v) for k,v in d.items()])
print result
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: `' '.join('{}: {:.4f}'.format(k, v) for k, v in d.items())`